# What does E_ALL and E_STRICT mean in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, error-reporting

I've following lines of code in one of my project's configuration file :

```
error_reporting((PHPFOX_DEBUG ? E_ALL | E_STRICT : 0));
```

I'm not able to figure out what this line is doing actually?

I checked in PHP documentation by putting in E_STRICT in search box but it didn't find any matching results.

So can some one please explain me the meaning of above line as well as usage of E_ALL and E_STRICT? What are these entities constants or variables?

Thanks.

Comment: Odd - Just googled it and within two clicks got http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Comment: @EdHeal:I went straight to PHP document and enterd a string E_STRICT into search box and I got a message : e_strict doesn't exist. That's why I asked for your help. Any ways can you please explain me the meaning of the code line I mentioned?

Comment: Probably the PHP search engine is written in PHP ;-) Try Google!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`E_ALL | E_STRICT` will display all possible errors/warnings and suggestions to improve interoperability.

So this is set when you are debugging mode for the code. Otherwise they are handled silently,

Comment: `E_ALL` is sufficient from 5.4.0.